# What is the order of addHandler parameters in Strophie Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xmpp, strophe

What is the order of addHandler parameters in strophe.while defining the handler ,why those parameters are ommitted?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details and 
mention the issue clearly what exactly you want. Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

there are some parameter in addHandler for us to filter what we are interest.

the addHandler method define in Strophe.js like this

`addHandler: function (handler, ns, name, type, id, from, options) { ... }`

if you are interest in message stanza ,you can

```
addHandler(callback, null, "message");
```

if you are interest in id, like you send an IQ request will have a IQ response

```
<iq id="123" type="get"></iq>

<iq id="123" type="result></iq>
```

and you want get the result iq stanza with id = "123", you can

```
addHandler(callback, null, "iq", "result", "123");
```

or you can just give id

```
addHandler(callback, null, null, null, "123");
```